# prove that $(n!)^{(n-1)!}$ divides (n!)!

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> prove that $(n!)^{(n-1)!}$ divides (n!)!

I know this question already exists but i'm looking for a **purely** number theory proof, no combinatorics.

My attempt: I tried to go about the concept of largest prime power that divides n! , which is given by $[\frac np]+[\frac{n}{p^2}] +......$ upto infinity (where [.] is the greatest integer function). So i tried to prove that largest power of prime *p* that divides (n!)! ≥ largest power of *p* that divides $(n!)^{(n-1)!}$, but i ended up with an ugly inequality with no idea how to proceed further.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050842/need-help-understanding-a-step-in-an-induction-proof proves it by induction.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357032/proving-that-frackkk-1-is-an-integer all therein linked posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a prime number $p$. For every $m\in  \mathbb{Z}$ let $\alpha_p(m)$ be the exponent of $p$ in factorization of $m$. Then
$$\alpha_p(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\bigg[\frac{n}{p^k}\bigg]$$
and
$$\alpha_p((n!)!) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\bigg[\frac{n!}{p^k}\bigg]$$
In particular, we have
$$\alpha_p\big((n!)^{(n-1)!}\big) = (n-1)!\cdot \alpha_p(n!) = (n-1)!\cdot \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\bigg[\frac{n}{p^k}\bigg]\bigg)$$
Since
$$x\cdot [y] \leq [x\cdot y]$$
for $x,y>0$ and $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, we deduce that
$$\alpha_p\big((n!)^{(n-1)!}\big) = (n-1)!\cdot \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\bigg[\frac{n}{p^k}\bigg]\bigg) =$$
$$= \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(n-1)!\cdot \bigg[\frac{n}{p^k}\bigg] \leq \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\bigg[(n-1)!\cdot \frac{n}{p^k}\bigg] = $$
$$= \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\bigg[\frac{n!}{p^k}\bigg] = \alpha_p\big((n!)!\big)$$

Comment: could you please tell me how  to prove ⋅[]≤[⋅]? thanks !

Comment: Sorry. I was confused for a moment. This inequality holds for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$. That was a gap in the argument. I fixed it thanks to your comment.

Comment: For the proof note that $x\cdot [y]$ is an integer (because $x\in \mathbb{Z}$) and $x\cdot [y] \leq x\cdot y$ (because $x,y>0$). Hence $x\cdot [y] \leq [x\cdot y]$ by definition.

Comment: i tried it this way, [y] = y -{y}, x[y]=xy-x{y} , [x.y] = xy -[x{y}] and [x{y}]<=x{y}

Comment: also, thank you so much for this answer, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can partition $n!$ elements into $(n-1)!$ groups of $n$ elements.

Therefore,
the group
$S_n \times S_n \times \cdots \times S_n$ (with $(n-1)!$ factors) is a subgroup of $S_{n!}$.

The claim follows by Lagrange's theorem of group theory.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684374/589